# Does closing a WPF Window also release all its data binding?

Tags: wpf, binding

I just want to know if the data binding still responds to source changed events after the window is closed. And if so, how to release all data bindings.

All I can find in MSDN is a sentence for Unloaded event:
"When Unloaded is raised and handled, the element that is the event source parent (as determined by Parent property) or any given element upwards in the logical or visual trees may have already been unset, meaning that data binding, resource references, and styles may not be set to their normal or last known run-time value. "

But it says "may not", so I still don't know it will or not. And it also says Unloaded event will not raise if the application is shutting down.

I found BindingOperation.ClearAllBindings(). But it seems only clear one object. To clear all, should I recursively clear the visual tree or the logical tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be unbound once the Garbage Collector cleans up the Window.

You can see similar behavior when manually disposing SqlConnections without closing them. Once the GC cleans them up, the connections close. Until then, you might exhast your connection pool.